# Facebook Messenger for iPhone: How to hide active status?

Tags: iphone, facebook

Just over six days ago, I sent a friend on Facebook a couple messages.

On the conversation view of Facebook Messenger for iPhone, I can see that they've received my messages because next to each message, there's a solid-blue circle with a white checkmark inside.

For several days after I sent the messages, I could see (under their name at the top) their active/online status, e.g., "Active 1d ago," but now, I just see, "Messenger."

I've waited long enough—I know it takes a little while—and "Messenger" hasn't changed to show their active status. Plus, all other conversations with my friends on Messenger show their active statuses.

How was my friend able to hide their active status while using Messenger?

1. I don't think they blocked me on Facebook because I can still see their profile.
2. I don't think they've added me to their "Restricted" friend list because I'm still able to see posts on their feed they've shared with Friends (nonpublic posts).
3. I don't think they've blocked my messages because I can still "Type a message..."

Answer (score 1):

1. How do you know your friend was using the iOS app (this may be a question for [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com))?
2. A blue circle with the white check means it was sent successfully, doesn't mean your friend was active or even read your message.
3. If you go to [facebook.com/messages](https://www.facebook.com/messages/) or [messenger.com](https://messenger.com) and navigate to the settings, you can toggle your online/offline status. Not sure how this carries over to the iPhone app showing active/not active. **Gear Icon (top left) → Settings → Account → Green Toggle.**

Asking your friend for more detail would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if your friend hasn't been active for more than a few days—I'm not sure what the exact cutoff duration is—Facebook doesn't show their active status, e.g., "Active 14h ago." It just shows "Facebook" or "Messenger" instead.

I'm not sure why Facebook would hide active statuses of friends who've been inactive for more than a few days. Probably for social proof: to make it seem like everyone's active on Facebook all the time.